# Linux: FFMPEG time lapse video from image comamnds work only collects a few images out of 1000s in directory PREMATURE TERMINATION

Tags: python, dataframe, video, ffmpeg

Good day
I read several ways on this site to make a time lapse video from a bunch of jpg images.  FFMPEG runs globbing all the jpgs. The result turns out perfect but it only does about 20 seconds worth and stops.  There are no errors below it seems.

I have read about a dozen ways to combine images to video on this site but all resulted in the same result as above.

https://superuser.com/questions/1499968/creating-timelapse-from-still-images-jpg-to-mp4-using-ffmpeg
https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-September/009419.html

also tried
 `ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg  -r 30 -q:v 2 output.mp4` same result

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 output.mp4                                                                 
ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --i                                                                     ncdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86                                                                     _64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-                                                                     protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disabl                                                                     e-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libdc1394 -                                                                     -enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --ena                                                                     ble-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-lib                                                                     opus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspe                                                                     ex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --ena                                                                     ble-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresam                                                                     ple --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enabl                                                                     e-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime                                                                     -cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mjpeg @ 0xd185c0] Changeing bps to 8
Input #0, image2, from '*.jpg':
  Duration: 00:09:33.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x960 [                                                                     SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
No pixel format specified, yuvj420p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] profile High, level 3.2
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] 264 - core 142 r2438 af8e768 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Cop                                                                     yleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deb                                                                     lock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 m                                                                     e_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chro                                                                     ma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1                                                                      interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1                                                                      b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scene                                                                     cut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin                                                                     =0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj420p(pc), 1                                                                     280x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   67 fps= 13 q=28.0 size=    2003kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate=45575.5kbits                                                                     frame=   70 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=    2524kB time=00:00:00.48 bitrate=43079.9kbits                                                                     frame=   73 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=    3046kB time=00:00:00.60 bitrate=41594.3kbits                                                                     frame=   76 fps= 11 q=28.0 size=    3589kB time=00:00:00.72 bitrate=40839.8kbits                                                                     frame=   86 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=    5410kB time=00:00:01.12 bitrate=39568.1kbits                                                                     frame=   92 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=    6493kB time=00:00:01.36 bitrate=39113.8kbits                                                                     frame=  101 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=    7855kB time=00:00:01.72 bitrate=37412.3kbits                                                                     frame=  108 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=    8950kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=36657.7kbits                                                                     frame=  115 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=   10118kB time=00:00:02.28 bitrate=36353.6kbits                                                                     frame=  120 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=   10961kB time=00:00:02.48 bitrate=36207.8kbits                                                                     frame=  128 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=   12310kB time=00:00:02.80 bitrate=36015.6kbits                                                                     frame=  134 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=   13323kB time=00:00:03.04 bitrate=35901.7kbits                                                                     frame=  139 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=   14168kB time=00:00:03.24 bitrate=35821.6kbits                                                                     frame=  142 fps= 11 q=28.0 size=   14676kB time=00:00:03.36 bitrate=35780.4kbits                                                                     frame=  154 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=   16439kB time=00:00:03.84 bitrate=35069.1kbits                                                                     frame=  159 fps= 11 q=28.0 size=   17328kB time=00:00:04.04 bitrate=35136.3kbits                                                                     frame=  167 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=   18774kB time=00:00:04.36 bitrate=35274.5kbits                                                                     frame=  173 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=   19864kB time=00:00:04.60 bitrate=35375.3kbits                                                                     frame=  182 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=   21492kB time=00:00:04.96 bitrate=35496.5kbits                                                                     frame=  187 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=   22389kB time=00:00:05.16 bitrate=35544.3kbits                                                                     frame=  190 fps= 11 q=28.0 size=   22935kB time=00:00:05.28 bitrate=35583.5kbits                                                                     frame=  196 fps= 11 q=28.0 size=   23972kB time=00:00:05.52 bitrate=35576.4kbits                                                                     frame=  208 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=   26168kB time=00:00:06.00 bitrate=35728.2kbits                                                                     frame=  214 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=   27303kB time=00:00:06.24 bitrate=35843.4kbits                                                                     frame=  224 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=   29130kB time=00:00:06.64 bitrate=35938.7kbits                                                                     frame=  224 fps=9.9 q=-1.0 Lsize=   38970kB time=00:00:08.88 bitrate=35950.7kbit                                                                     s/s
video:38968kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing                                                                      overhead: 0.005002%
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] frame I:6     Avg QP:27.08  size:209868
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] frame P:218   Avg QP:29.42  size:177263
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] mb I  I16..4:  0.0% 98.9%  1.1%
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] mb P  I16..4:  0.0% 90.0%  0.1%  P16..4:  2.0%  4.1%  3.7%                                                                       0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] 8x8 transform intra:99.8% inter:88.2%
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 100.0% 0.0% 0.0% inter: 97.4% 0.0%                                                                      0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] i16 v,h,dc,p: 58% 29% 12%  0%
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  7% 11% 44%  6%  6%  5%  8%                                                                       6%  8%
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 16% 13%  9%  9%  7% 10%                                                                       9% 10%
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] i8c dc,h,v,p: 100%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] Weighted P-Frames: Y:13.3% UV:0.5%
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] ref P L0: 37.5%  9.4% 28.4% 22.9%  1.8%
[libx264 @ 0xd1e140] kb/s:35627.30
```

Comment: Maybe the glob pattern is not taking all the files you think.

Comment: Check that there are no 0-sized files. Remove them.

Comment: Your ffmpeg is really old. Considering updating before doing anything else as development is very active and doing so will allow you to avoid already fixed bugs. [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos).

Comment: Hi Gyan , i had a feeling it was something like that but didnt check as i assumed ffmpeg was developed enough to know valid jpg files. it appears to be working  thank you